How to control multichannel curves in Swift via CIFilter?
I try to recreate Photoshop's curve adjustment. The tool contains an array with arrays of curve points bound to a chanellID: 0-composite, 1-r, 2-g, 3-b. If I want to work only with a composite channel, the CIToneCurve filter is enough. But it has a limit of 5 points.
And I don't understand how to achieve complete control of every channel. I was thrown to use CIColorMatrix to decompose my image into a channel. But I can't compose them back (I can, but with artifacts).
So, my last stop was the CIColorCurve filter. But it is so undocumented.
What is the right way to implement CIFilter with full-channel control? Or could you suggest (or help to create) a CIKernel for this? One of my bad throws is:
import UIKit.UIImage
import CoreImage

struct Curve {
    
    let ciFilter: CIFilter = .toneCurve()
    
    var data: [Int : [(Double, Double)]] = [:]
    var input: CIImage?
    
    var output: CIImage? {
        guard var input else { return nil }
        
        let channels: [CIImage?] = (0...2).map { index in
            let colorMatrix = CIFilter.colorMatrix()
            colorMatrix.inputImage = input
            
            colorMatrix.rVector = .init(x: index == 0 ? 1 : 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0)
            colorMatrix.gVector = .init(x: 0, y: index == 1 ? 1 : 0, z: 0, w: 0)
            colorMatrix.bVector = .init(x: 0, y: 0, z: index == 2 ? 1 : 0, w: 0)
//            colorMatrix.biasVector = .init(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1)
              
            return colorMatrix.outputImage
        }
        
        let toneChannels = ([input] + channels).enumerated().compactMap { index, channel in
            if let data = data[index] {
                let toneCurve = CIFilter.toneCurve()
                toneCurve.inputImage = channel
                toneCurve.point0 = CGPoint(x: data[0].1 / 255, y: data[0].0 / 255)
                toneCurve.point1 = CGPoint(x: data[1].1 / 255, y: data[1].0 / 255)
                toneCurve.point2 = CGPoint(x: data[2].1 / 255, y: data[2].0 / 255)
                toneCurve.point3 = CGPoint(x: data[3].1 / 255, y: data[3].0 / 255)
                toneCurve.point4 = CGPoint(x: data[4].1 / 255, y: data[4].0 / 255)
                return toneCurve.outputImage
            }
            return channel
        }

        return toneChannels[1].composited(over: toneChannels[2]).composited(over: toneChannels[3]).composited(over: toneChannels[0])
    }
    
}


I was thrown using CIToneCurve, but it does not provide complete control. I was thrown to decompose my image via CIColorMatrix, but I can't compose it back. I expect complete control over curves and channels.

did you try colorCurvesFilter?

Yes, I did. However, I can't find any documentation about how to work with curve data. I suppose I need to make an NxN float matrix where the element's position is a relative x on the curve's area, and the element's value is my y. But I failed. It's not working correctly for me now.

You can check out the free Filter Magic app on the App Store. It lets you play with all the filters and also adds additional documentation.

Sadly, it’s only a documentation based demoapp.
